# Simple metronome - Play an AIF every x number of milliseconds

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-audio

I've had a look at the metronome sample given by Apple, however, the sample is too complicated and includes things not needed in my project.

Is there a simple way to make a system sound play every x number of milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of warning... NSTimer is not accurate, if timing is important or you're trying to keep a steady beat.

Answer (score 1):

[Look into NSTimer.](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

You are going to want to do something like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:x target:self selector:@selector(yourMethodHere:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The Apple examples can help with the actual code needed to play the sound file, and NSTimer should be pretty straightforward to learn how to use.

[Another good NSTimer resource can be found at CocoaDev.](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTimer)

Comment: Works perfectly thanks!

And thanks a lot for the links as well. Some good reading.